# Reduce size of Access database

Tags: database, ms-access-2013, downsize

I have an Access database,  and it is 14 Mb!

I really want to reduce the size as I takes a minute to download from the server.

I've embedded images as backgrounds on the forms.  However,  converting the JPG to PNG or GIF  doesn't seem to reduce the file size at all.

Compacting also doesn't do much.

Please advise if anyone knows how to reduce the file size significantly

Thanks!!

Comment: *"deleting of using PNG instead of JPG images"* - what? Note that 7z compresses Access DBs very well (for the downloading issue).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reducing Access database size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755230/reducing-access-database-size)