# Reducing Access database size

Tags: ms-access-2013, filesize

I have an Access database, and it is 14 Mb!

I really want to reduce the size as I takes a minute to download from the server.

I've embedded images as backgrounds on the forms. However, converting the JPG to PNG or GIF doesn't seem to reduce the file size at all.

Compacting also doesn't do much.

Please advise if anyone knows how to reduce the file size significantly

Thanks!!

Comment: *I really want to reduce the size as I takes a minute to download from the server.* Back in my day dial-up modems took a minute to connect to the internet, uphill both ways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce size of Access database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737484/reduce-size-of-access-database)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: Move the pictures off the database to separate files.

That said, 14 MB isn't really that much for an Access database.

Comment: What if I wanted to include the pictures in the database?  Is there another way to downsizd the file?

Comment: No, they have to move out of the database.

Comment: I have removed all images from the database,  the file size still hasn't been reduced.  Any idea why or what else can be done?

Comment: If you have compacted, the only option left is to create a new database and import all objects from the present database.